# how to switch strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what I've tried:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if str(list2[0]) == list1[i][0]:
         list1.remove(str(list2[0]))
print(list1)
```

Comment: what does `list2` has to do with the problem? you simply remove `'apple'` no? Also, you are removing from `list1` when you should remove from `list1[i]`

Comment: `withoutapplelist = [[subitem for subitem in item if subitem != "apple"] for item in list1]`

Answer (score 1):

You are not consistly operating on the inner lists - your outer list contains no string "apple". You try to remove "apple" from `list1`:

> ```
> list1 = [["apple", "bd", "go", "d", "e"], ["bd", "e", "d", "go", "apple"],
>          ["go", "d", "e", "bd", "apple"], ["d", "bd", "apple", "go", "e"], 
>          ["e", "apple", "go", "bd", "d"]]
>
> list2 = ["apple", "bd", "e", "d", "go"]
>
> for i in range(len(list1)):
>     if str(list2[0]) == list1[i][0]:
>          list1.remove(str(list2[0]))   # list1 only contains lists, not strings
> print(list1)
> ```

```
# iterate over all inner lists    
for inner in list1:
    # and remove "apple"
    inner.remove(list2[0]) 
    
print(list1)
```

Output:

```
[['bd', 'go', 'd', 'e'], ['bd', 'e', 'd', 'go'], ['go', 'd', 'e', 'bd'],
 ['d', 'bd', 'go', 'e'], ['e', 'go', 'bd', 'd']]
```

If you want to create a new one, do it like so:

```
no_apple = []

for inner in list1:
    # filter inners with list comprehension, expluce list2[0]
    no_apple.append([i for i in inner if i != list2[0]])
    
print(no_apple)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a restriction to create a new list?

You can create a new list for each list inside list1 and append them in a new list

```
answer = []
for inside_list in list1:
  new_inside_list = [value for value in inside_list if value not in list2]
  answer.append(new_inside_list)
```

This removes every element of list2 that appears in list1.

Take care that new_inside_list can result in an empty list. Just check if it is empty before append to answer